# ConnectionOptions Username property

Tags: c#, windows, service, wmi

I'm using WMI to get services list from a remote server.

when I type Username property:

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Username = "User1";
options.Password = "MyPassword";
```

I have this error:

> Erreur    1   'TstServicesController.ConnectionOptions' ne contient pas une
>   définition pour 'Username' et aucune méthode d'extension 'Username'
>   acceptant un premier argument de type
>   'TstServicesController.ConnectionOptions' n'a été trouvée (une
>   directive using ou une référence d'assembly est-elle
>   manquante ?)  d:\Profiles\adridi\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\Tst Services
>   Controller\TstServicesController\AddNewSrv.cs 58  21  TstServicesController

Did I miss a "using" directive? I'm already using:

```
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;
```

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Ooops, it's my mistake,

I declared a local ConnectionOptions class that not contain any property.

Thanks !